# ERROR while insert data to mysql using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, debugging, mysqli

I am new to jquery ,i have some trouble while inserting data to mysql database using jquery.
this is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
staff registration
</title>
<body>
<form>
Staff Id:<input type="text" id="staffid"><br>
Password:<input type="password" id="password1"><br>
Re-enter Password:<input type="password" id="password2"><br>
Email:<input type="email"   id="email"><br>
Gender:<input type="text" id="gender"><br>
Qualification:<input type="text" id="qualification"><br>
Course 1:<input type="text" id="course1"><br>
Course 2:<input type="text" id="course2"><br>
Course 3:<input type="text" id="course3"><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="CREATE">
</form>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#submit").click(function(){
 var staffid=$("#staffid").val();
 var password1=$("#password1").val();
 var password2=$("#password2").val();
 var email=$("#email").val();
 var gender=$("#gender").val();
 var qualification=$("#qualification").val();
 var course1=$("#course1").val();
 var course2=$("#course2").val();
 var course3=$("#course3").val();
 $.post("insert.php",{si:staffid,pwd1:password1,pwd2:password2,
 email:eml,gender:gen,qualification:qal,course1:c1,course2:c2,course3:c3},
 function(data){
     alert(data);
 }); 
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my php file named insert.php

```
<?php
 $con=new mysqli("localhost","root","","flash");
    $si=$_POST['si'];
    $pwd1=$_POST['pwd1'];
    $pwd2=$_POST['pwd2'];
    $eml=$_POST['eml'];
    $gen=$_POST['gen'];
    $qal=$_POST['qal'];
    $c1=$_POST['c1'];
    $c2=$_POST['c2'];
    $c3=$_POST['c3'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO staff(staff_id,password,email_id,gender,qualification,course_1,course_2,course_3) VALUES('$si','$pwd2','$eml','$gen','$qal','$c1','$c2','$c3')";
    $con->query($sql);

?>
```

nothing will happen while i click submit button

please anyone help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the non-slim build, available here http://jquery.com/download/, such as:

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Also you had issue while making the json for the post, here is the rectified version

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
staff registration
</title>
<body>
<form>
Staff Id:<input type="text" id="staffid"><br>
Password:<input type="password" id="password1"><br>
Re-enter Password:<input type="password" id="password2"><br>
Email:<input type="email"   id="email"><br>
Gender:<input type="text" id="gender"><br>
Qualification:<input type="text" id="qualification"><br>
Course 1:<input type="text" id="course1"><br>
Course 2:<input type="text" id="course2"><br>
Course 3:<input type="text" id="course3"><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="CREATE">
</form>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#submit").click(function(){
 var staffid=$("#staffid").val();
 var password1=$("#password1").val();
 var password2=$("#password2").val();
 var email=$("#email").val();
 var gender=$("#gender").val();
 var qualification=$("#qualification").val();
 var course1=$("#course1").val();
 var course2=$("#course2").val();
 var course3=$("#course3").val();
 $.post("insert.php",{si:staffid,pwd1:password1,pwd2:password2,
 eml:email,gen:gender,qal:qualification,c1:course1,c2:course2,c3:course3},
 function(data){
     alert(data);
 }); 
});</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry ,there is no change

Comment: Strange... Have you changed the jQuery and the json format as stated above?

Comment: Have you checked your database connection?

Comment: I cant understand whats wrong in json format both are looking similar

Comment: They both look similar but they are not. You have misplaced key and value. Use https://www.diffchecker.com to check difference